# How to get these parameter values in javascript from select2 selecting event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-select2

I am storing some custom values whenever a user selects an option in 'selecting' select2 event:

```
$(select2Elm).on('select2:selecting', async function (e) {
   e.params.args.data.added = true;
   e.params.args.data.removed = false;
});
```

the above `select2` is located inside a **datatable's** row, so when I click on the row's ***Save*** button I call this function and now I dont know how to get those custom values I have stored once selected:

```
function saveGroupChanges(elm) {
    var select2Elm = elm.closest('tr').getElementsByClassName('typeselectUsers')[0];
}
```

since I am using **datatables** I need to use `closest` in order to get the values of the current row.

Comment: Please add more code - this is not enough...

Comment: @biberman Why do you think this is not enough? Question is clear, how to get those values in saveGroupChanges function?

Comment: Because the issue can't be reproduced. Therefor you should create a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)...